# Extra data manipulation with end to end encryption

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, end-to-end

Would it be possible to store some data as tables in a system, where users talk with each other through a server using end to end encryption. Figuratively, let's say end points A and B talk to each other through a server using end to end encryption. This basically means all of the messages flowing from A to B or vice versa are only decryptable between these two end points. So I want to create a schema, say a webserver, where I would create a table as follows:

```
From   To         Content               HasMessageBeenSend
 A      B    encrypted text                    0
 B      A    some other encrypted text         1
```

Would it be possible to create such a schema above in the server? For example, A writes into database this encrypted text as well as the receiver the sender sides, but because messages are encrypted, except of this content area, all other information is public and can be readable by the server.

Comment: This is not programming question. Have a look at signal protocol. Not, encrypted email already does what you asked.

Comment: @kelalaka hey thanks for the help you are a life saver! one question still nibbles my mind tho, can a server decide on when to send a message to other side or lets say have the messages in pending status and then makes some checks, based on that delivers it to other side.  is it also possible?

Comment: The serer can try to send the message to the user immediately but if the user is not connected it must store or wait the user to connect depend on the application...